# Getting unusual counts in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

In the below query I'm getting some odd results -- specifically, I'm getting the same counts for both categories (current year and all time) and I can't figure out why that would be.  Here's my query:

```
SELECT eventlist.isid, eventlist.name, COUNT(currentyearcount.arid) AS currentyearcount, COUNT(allreports.arid) AS allreports
FROM eventlist
LEFT JOIN artist_reports currentyearcount ON eventlist.isid = currentyearcount.CompanyID AND currentyearcount.event_year = 2015
JOIN artist_reports allreports ON eventlist.isid = allreports.CompanyID
GROUP BY eventlist.isid
```

I'm getting results like this:

```
isid    name    currentyearcount  allreports
1234    Name1   33                33
5678    Name2   105               105
9012    Name3   0                 63
```

I'm not sure why Name3 would show 0 for currentyearcount when really they should all be showing 0 as there aren't any reports for the current year yet.

UPDATE:  Here's the correct query thanks to Aleksandar's comments:

```
SELECT eventlist.isid, eventlist.name, SUM(CASE WHEN artist_reports.arid IS NOT NULL AND artist_reports.event_year = 2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS currentyearcount, SUM(CASE WHEN artist_reports.arid IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalcount
FROM eventlist
LEFT JOIN artist_reports ON eventlist.isid = artist_reports.CompanyID
GROUP BY eventlist.isid
```

Comment: Because there may not be any records for the current year.

Comment: tables structure and diagram would be very helpful here. Do you have 2 or 3 tables? I'm blind guessing now but maybe instead of COUNT(currentyearcount.arid) you should use COUNT(CASE WHEN column_name_where_year_of_raport_is = 2015)...

Comment: Using SUM(CASE WHEN did it.  I've updated my query to reflect, how can I give you credit for this?

Comment: I have no clue :) Important thing is that the problem is solved. I'm glad i could help GL